# Proof of Roger Heath-Brown: Interchanging Solutions of Involution

Tags: number-theory, fixed-point-theorems, involutions

On page 20 of ["Proofs from THE BOOK" (click here)](http://u.cs.biu.ac.il/~margolis/Sadna/Proofs%20rom%20the%20Book%203rd%20Ed..pdf) a proof of representing number as sum of two square is given. The proof is due to  Roger Heath-Brown (1971,appeared in 1984). The first part of the proof is -[image]

I didn't get the below paragraph at all-

> What do we get from the study of $f$ ? The main observation is that
>   since $f$ maps the sets $T$ and $U$ to their complements, it also
>   interchanges the elements in $T\setminus U$ with these in $U\setminus T$.
>    That is, there is the same number of solutions in $U$ that are not
>   in T as there are solutions in T that are not in U
>   -so $T$ and $U$ have the same cardinality.

So my questions is-

**How does  $f$ interchanges the elements in $T\setminus U$ with these in $U\setminus T$?**

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $\,S\,$ is partitioned into four pairwise disjoint sets:
 $$S = (T\cap U) \cup (T\setminus U) \cup (U\setminus T) \cup(S\setminus(T\cup U)). \tag{1}$$
We are given that the involution $\,f\,$ has no fixed points, and maps
$\,T\,$ to $\,S\setminus T\,$ and $\,U\,$ to $\,S\setminus U.\,$

Then it must map their intersection $\,T\cap U\,$ to
$$ (S\setminus T)\cap(S\setminus U) = S\setminus(T\cup U). \tag{2}$$
The exact same reasoning applies to their complements. This
means that $\,f\,$ maps $\,S\setminus T\,$ to $\,T\,$ and
$\,S\setminus U\,$ to $\,U.\,$ Thus their intersection as in
equation $(2)$ gets mapped to $\,T\cap U.\,$
The two remaining parts of $\,S\,$ are
 $\,T\setminus U\,$ and $\,U\setminus T.\,$
Each gets mapped to the other part since the first and
fourth parts are mapped by $\,f\,$ to each other and
since both $\,T\,$ and $\,U\,$ get mapped to their complements.

Equation $(1)$ is true for **any** set $\,S\,$
and with any given
$\,T\subseteq S\,$ and $\,U\subseteq S.\,$
The subsets $\,T\,$ and $\,U\,$ may or may not
be disjoint. Their union $\,T\cup U\,$ may or
may not be equal to $\,S.\,$ One of the subsets
may or may not be a subset of the other. In other
words, **any** of the four parts of the
partition in equation $(1)$ may or may not be
the empty set depending of the specific subsets
$\,T\,$ and $\,U.\,$

An example is for $\,p=13\,$ where $\,(1,1,-3)\in S\,$ 
and $\,(1,3,-1)\in S\,$ which are not in $\,T\cup U. $

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3491121/why-exactly-3-involutions-are-used-in-the-proof-of-roger-heath-brown

Comment: @Andrew Thanks. I have corrected my answer. I hope it is okay now.

Comment: Could have used Morgans law

Comment: @Andrew That is exactly what equation (2) is. I just didn't use the phrase De Morgan's law.